# has_many association .build is not saving object in DB for Rails 6.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I'm upgrading to Rails 6.1, and have the following associations in my model

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :classifications, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :order_lines, dependent: :destroy
end
```

For this following snippet:

```
p = Product.new
p.classifications.build name: 'my name'
p.order_lines.build line_number: '123'
p.save
```

If I run it in my existing code env (Rails 6.0, Ruby 2.7.7), it works as expected. However, if I run it against Rails 6.1, the `classifications` object is stored in the DB, whereas the `order_line` is dropped. There is no SQL statement that attempts to write it to the DB, and checking `p.order_lines.inspect` after the save, returns an empty `CollectionProxy`.
Changing the order of how we build the objects had no impact. Changing the order of how the association is defined in the model DID change the behaviour (`order_line` was persisted and `classifications` wasn't)

Interestingly enough, if I switch to

```
p = Product.create # instead of .new
# rest of snippet
```

It works as expected against Rails 6.1, and both `order_line` and `classification` were stored. This is very confusing behaviour, and I have no idea what is introducing it. Any thoughts?

EDIT: the behaviour is consistent with any two `has_many` associations I define on any model. The association defined first in the model gets saved, while the other one gets dropped. I tried swapping them around and reloading my console, and the one that gets saved vs dropped was swapped.

Comment: Did you mean to write `p.order_lines.build line_number: '123'`? You're currently calling a method instead of passing a hash. `build` is also just an alias of `new` which exists for legacy reasons.

Comment: oh good catch... yes, I meant to pass a hash.

Comment: Try running `p.order_lines.errors.full_messages` to see if any of the validations failed. Am I right in assuming that it's join table between products and orders? In that case I would guess that it's failing to save since it needs an order.

Comment: Double checked, and it's not a validation issue. The weird thing is that if I repeat all steps, just switch `Product.new` to `Product.create` it would work, which further supports that this is not validation related.

Comment: can't reproduce this, which is the only reason you don't have an answer. can you do it from `bin/rails _6.1.0_ new myapp`, because that's how i start when answering a hard debugging question. the code that you show works for me in `rails v6.0.0` and `rails v6.1.0`.

Comment: come'on, open up the vault, show us your dirty magic and monkeypatches :D there must be some skeletons in your codebase that causes this sideeffect